# how to reset the axix of HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am very new to html5.
infact this is my first work.

I am working on a small project. Part of the project is to read an xml file which has shapes in it

```
  <Graphic>
     <object_type>LINE</object_type>
     <field_1>3.6082475185394287</field_1>
     <field_2>541.23712158203125</field_2>
     <field_3>28.86598014831543</field_3>
     <field_4>474.48452758789062</field_4>
     <field_6 />
     <field_7 />
     <field_8 />
     <field_9 />
  </Graphic>
  <Graphic>
     <object_type>LINE</object_type>
     <field_1>10.824742317199707</field_1>
     <field_2>562.8865966796875</field_2>
     <field_3>3.6082475185394287</field_3>
     <field_4>541.23712158203125</field_4>
     <field_6 />
     <field_7 />
     <field_8 />
     <field_9 />
  </Graphic>
```

after reading the xml file i am iterating through the coordinates. and drawing the object on the html5 canvas.

I have two troubles....

1) the photo is being drawn upside down... so i need to rotate the canvas
[Image can be viewed here](http://agilani.byethost10.com/img.jpg)

2) i need to scale the whole object within the canvas. for now i am dividing every coordinate with 8 to scale it down. how i can scale it according to screen resolution and canvas...

cannot get my head around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to get the object width and height, you just need to calculate the scale factor related to the canvas:

```
var scaleFactorW = canvas.width/obj.width,
    scaleFactorH = canvas.height/obj.height;

context.scale(scaleFactorW , scaleFactorH);
startDrawing(obj);
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/6HLp4/) at *jsfiddle.net*

---

**EDIT:**

To maintain the object proportions for different canvas resolutions we need to calculate a scale factor that verifies the max scale based on canvas aspect ratio and the object proportions.

```
var canvasAspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
var objAspectRatio = obj.width / obj.height;

var scaleFactor = 1;

if (canvasAspectRatio > objAspectRatio) {        
    scaleFactor = canvas.height / obj.height;        
} else {
    scaleFactor = canvas.width / obj.width;        
}
context.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

startDrawing(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I was able to do pretty much all of my work with the help you have provided. However i am still facing few issues...

1) when the page first loads, i am checking screen width and height and resizing my canvas accordingly. then when someone resize the window, i am resizing the canvas... doing so the scaling method you have provided is making the drawing squashed. i have tried redrawing and still the same issue... any insight on that

Comment: In the example above I don't care about aspect ratio. I just fit the object on the canvas no matter is the canvas aspect ratio. So on, I'll try to update the answer to do that.

Comment: I have nearly 783 objects to draw in one file and in one file more than 1000. Using your method everything works fine except it it slows the redrawing upon re-sizing the window and canvas. Any suggestions for this...?

Comment: The use of `context.scale` too many times may slow things down. You could determine what is the aspect ratio of your application instead of each object. Let's say that your graphics are ready to be drawn at 800x600 canvas resolution. For different displays or different resolutions just calculate the scaleFactor and use context.scale once.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer to the first question after doing bit of maths...

my canvas was

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="background: #FFFFFF; border: 5px solid black;" role="img">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
```

and javascript became...

```
        startDrawing(obj);

        // rotate 180 degrees clockwise
        context.rotate(180*(Math.PI/180));

        // translate context to opposite of your actual canvas
        context.translate(-800, -500);
```

still need the answer for the 2nd question.... the scaling